# Local Mosquitto MQTT Broker to AWSIoT Thing

Tags: amazon-web-services, connection, mqtt, mosquitto, bridge

I am attempting to bridge a local Mosquitto broker to an AWSIoT core thing. Essentially my end goal is to set up a communication scheme as listed below:

Codesys runtime file -> local Mosquitto broker (on IPC) -> MQTT Bridge -> AWSIoT Core (Thing - MQTT Client for confirmation of data transfer)

My communication set up from the Codesys runtime file to the local broker works, but the communication from the local broker over the MQTT bridge to the AWSIoT Core Thing is not working. I am attempting to perform the data transfer verification by using the MQTT Client tool on the AWS server. I have attached a copy of my mosquitto.conf and the bridge.conf files to verify correct setup. Can someone please take a look at my setup and see if its correct or possibly missing something? I shall gladly appreciate any help that can and will afforded my way.

Regards.

[image]

Please refer to my problem description

Comment: Please do not post images of text, they are very hard to read (impossible for people that use screen readers) and un searchable. Please replace the image with the actual text and use the toolbar to format it.